# Click and Be asked where to save with ASP classic

Tags: jquery, asp-classic, download

I am using jquery $.post function to just call an asp script.  This script needs to copy a file I have on the server and save it on the clients machine.  I would like for the user to use the typical save window to save the file where they want instead of hardcoding a path in the asp.  Any suggesitons?

This is the asp I have:

```
<%
    'Name of finished file
ImageFile = "sampleXML.xml"


'Destination of finsished file
DestFolder = ""

'Download address of file
URL = "http://localhost/MyWeb/sampleXML.xml"
'Wscript.Echo(URL)

Set xml = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
xml.Open "GET", URL, False
xml.Send

set oStream = createobject("Adodb.Stream")
Const adTypeBinary = 1
Const adSaveCreateOverWrite = 2
Const adSaveCreateNotExist = 1 

oStream.type = adTypeBinary
oStream.open
oStream.write xml.responseBody

' Use this form to overwrite a file if it already exists
oStream.savetofile DestFolder & ImageFile, adSaveCreateOverWrite

oStream.close

set oStream = nothing
Set xml = Nothing

%>
```

and the jquery:

```
$("#sampleXML").click(function () {
     $.post('downloadXML.asp');
 });
```

Thank you

Comment: You need open it in a new tab or window and correctly set the content type of the returning document in the header.  That will trigger a save dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  Finally found a useful page for asp classic.

http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/how-do-i-prompt-a-save-as-dialog-for-an-accepted-mime-type.html

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to do this. It is a standard feature that a popup window opens to ask to download or save. There is no way to change these options because doing so could expose visitors to exploits.